# How to search an object for a value?

Tags: powershell, object, properties, powershell-v5.1

Let's say you have a giant object - one which may or may not have nested arrays / objects,

```
# Assuming 'user1' exists in the current domain    
$obj = Get-ADUser 'user1' -Properties *
```

and I want to search that object for the string `SMTP` case-insensitively...

**What I tried**

```
$obj | Select-String "SMTP"
```

But it does not work because the match is inside a nested *Collection*... to be concise, it sits inside the property `$obj.proxyAddresses`.

If I run `$obj.proxyAddress.GetType()` it returns:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                      BaseType
-------- -------- ----                      --------
True     False    ADPropertyValueCollection System.Collections.CollectionBase
```

What's the best way to go about this? I know you could loop through the properties and look for it manually using wildcard matching or `.Contains()`, but I'd prefer a built in solution.

Thus, it would be a `grep` for objects and not only strings.

Comment: What do you want returned? True or false , the parent object?

Comment: @ArcSet Probably just the object or the string value depending on which type it finds. Similar to how `grep` finds one line and shows only that line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution.  It can be very slow depending on what depth you search to; but a depth of 1 or 2 works well for your scenario:

```
function Find-ValueMatchingCondition {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [PSObject]$InputObject
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ScriptBlock]$Condition
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [Int]$Depth = 10
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Name = 'InputObject'
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes]$PropertyTypesToSearch = ([System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes]::Properties)

    )
    Process {
        if ($InputObject -ne $null) {
            if ($InputObject | Where-Object -FilterScript $Condition) {
                New-Object -TypeName 'PSObject' -Property @{Name=$Name;Value=$InputObject}
            }
            #also test children (regardless of whether we've found a match
            if (($Depth -gt 0)  -and -not ($InputObject.GetType().IsPrimitive -or ($InputObject -is 'System.String'))) {
                [string[]]$members = Get-Member -InputObject $InputObject -MemberType $PropertyTypesToSearch | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
                ForEach ($member in $members) {
                    $InputObject."$member" | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null} | Find-ValueMatchingCondition -Condition $Condition -Depth ($Depth - 1) -Name $member | ForEach-Object {$_.Name = ('{0}.{1}' -f $Name, $_.Name);$_}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Get-AdUser $env:username -Properties * `
    | Find-ValueMatchingCondition -Condition {$_ -like '*SMTP*'} -Depth 2
```

Example Results:

```
Value                                           Name                                  
-----                                           ----                                  
smtp:SomeOne@myCompany.com                      InputObject.msExchShadowProxyAddresses
SMTP:some.one@myCompany.co.uk                   InputObject.msExchShadowProxyAddresses
smtp:username@myCompany.com                     InputObject.msExchShadowProxyAddresses
smtp:some.one@myCompany.mail.onmicrosoft.com    InputObject.msExchShadowProxyAddresses    
smtp:SomeOne@myCompany.com                      InputObject.proxyAddresses  
SMTP:some.one@myCompany.co.uk                   InputObject.proxyAddresses  
smtp:username@myCompany.com                     InputObject.proxyAddresses  
smtp:some.one@myCompany.mail.onmicrosoft.com    InputObject.proxyAddresses     
SMTP:some.one@myCompany.mail.onmicrosoft.com    InputObject.targetAddress
```

---

## Explanation

`Find-ValueMatchingCondition` is a function which takes a given object (`InputObject`) and tests each of its properties against a given condition, recursively.

The function is divided into two parts.  The first part is the testing of the input object itself against the condition:

```
if ($InputObject | Where-Object -FilterScript $Condition) {
    New-Object -TypeName 'PSObject' -Property @{Name=$Name;Value=$InputObject}
}
```

This says, where the value of `$InputObject` matches the given `$Condition` then return a new custom object with two properties; `Name` and `Value`.  `Name` is the name of the input object (passed via the function's `Name` parameter), and `Value` is, as you'd expect, the object's value.  If `$InputObject` is an array, each of the values in the array is assessed individually.  The name of the root object passed in is defaulted as `"InputObject"`; but you can override this value to whatever you like when calling the function.

The second part of the function is where we handle recursion:

```
if (($Depth -gt 0)  -and -not ($InputObject.GetType().IsPrimitive -or ($InputObject -is 'System.String'))) {
    [string[]]$members = Get-Member -InputObject $InputObject -MemberType $PropertyTypesToSearch | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    ForEach ($member in $members) {
        $InputObject."$member" | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null} | Find-ValueMatchingCondition -Condition $Condition -Depth ($Depth - 1) -Name $member | ForEach-Object {$_.Name = ('{0}.{1}' -f $Name, $_.Name);$_}
    }
}
```

The `If` statement checks how deep we've gone into the original object (i.e. since each of an objects properties may have properties of their own, to a potentially infinite level (since properties may point back to the parent), it's best to limit how deep we can go.  This is essentially the same purpose as the `ConvertTo-Json`'s `Depth` parameter.

The `If` statement also checks the object's type.  i.e. for most primitive types, that type holds the value, and we're not interested in their properties/methods (primitive types don't have any properties, but do have various methods, which may be scanned depending on `$PropertyTypeToSearch`).  Likewise if we're looking for `-Condition {$_ -eq 6}` we wouldn't want all strings of length 6; so we don't want to drill down into the string's properties.  This filter could likely be improved further to help ignore other types / we could alter the function to provide another optional script block parameter (e.g. `$TypeCondition`) to allow the caller to refine this to their needs at runtime.

After we've tested whether we want to drill down into this type's members, we then fetch a list of members.  Here we can use the `$PropertyTypesToSearch` parameter to change what we search on.  By default we're interested in members of type `Property`; but we may want to only scan those of type `NoteProperty`; especially if dealing with custom objects.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmembertypes?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0 for more info on the various options this provides.

Once we've selected what members/properties of the input object we wish to inspect, we fetch each in turn, ensure they're not null, then recurse (i.e. call `Find-ValueMatchingCondition`).  In this recursion, we decrement `$Depth` by one (i.e. since we've already gone down 1 level & we stop at level 0), and pass the name of this member to the function's `Name` parameter.

Finally, for any returned values (i.e. the custom objects created by part 1 of the function, as outlined above), we prepend the `$Name` of our current InputObject to the name of the returned value, then return this amended object.  This ensures that each object returned has a Name representing the full path from the root InputObject down to the member matching the condition, and gives the value which matched.

Comment: Good call; agreed that that's probably a better default

Answer (score 4):

<sup>**Note**: This answer contains **background information** and offers a **quick-and-dirty approach that requires no custom functionality**.

For a more **more thorough, systematic approach** based on reflection via a **custom function**, see [JohnLBevan's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52616732/45375).</sup>

`Select-String` operates on *strings*, and when it coerces an input object of a different type to a string, it essentially calls `.ToString()` on it, which often yields generic representations such as the mere type name and typically *not* an enumeration of the properties.
Note that an object's `.ToString()` representation is *not* the same as PowerShell's default output to the console, which is much richer.

If all you're looking for is to **find a substring in the *for-display* string representation of an object**, you can pipe to `Out-String -Stream` before piping to `Select-String`:

```sh
$obj | Out-String -Stream | Select-String "SMTP"
```

`Out-String` creates a *string* representation that is the same as what renders to the *console* by default (it uses PowerShell's output-formatting system); adding `-Stream` emits that representation *line by line*, whereas by default a single, multi-line string is emitted.

Note: Recent versions of PowerShell come with **convenience function `oss`**, which *wraps* `Out-String -Stream`:

```sh
$obj | oss | Select-String "SMTP"
```

Of course, **this method will only work if the for-display representation actually shows the data of interest** - see caveats below.

That said, **searching in the for-display representations is arguably what `Select-String` should do *by default*** - see [GitHub issue #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726#issuecomment-567628146)

**Caveats**:

- If the formatted representation happens to be *tabular* and your search string is a property *name*, the value of interest may be on the *next* line.

  - You can address this by **forcing a *list*-style display - where each property occupies a line of its own (both name and value) -** as follows:

    ```sh
     $obj | Format-List | Out-String -Stream | Select-String "SMTP"
    ```
  - If you anticipate multi-line property values, you can **use `Select-String`'s `-Context` parameter to include lines *surrounding* a match**, such as `-Context 0,1` to also output the line *after* a match.
  - If you know that the values of interest are in a ***collection-valued* property**, you can **use `$FormatEnumerationLimit = -1` to force listing of *all* elements** (by default, only the first 4 elements are displayed).

    - Caveat: As of PowerShell Core 6.1.0, `$FormatEnumerationLimit` is only effective if set in the *global* scope - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/888).
    - However, once you hit the need to set preference variable `$FormatEnumerationLimit`, it's time to consider the more thorough solution based on a custom function in [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52616732/45375).
- Values may get *truncated* in the representation, because `Out-String` assumes a fixed line width; you can use `-Width` to change that, but be careful with large numbers, because tabular representations then use the full width for every output line.