# How to use a function to get objects from a pipeline as strings?

Tags: powershell

Command that output the result in string instead of objects:

```
ls | Out-String -Stream
```

Output:

```
    Directory: C:\MyPath\dir1

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          2022-01-22  5:34 PM              0 1.txt
-a---          2022-01-22  5:34 PM              0 2.txt
-a---          2022-01-22  5:34 PM              0 3.txt
```

I tried to get the same result using a function:

```
function f {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        $Content
    )
    
    process {
        $Content | Out-String -Stream
    }
}

ls | f
```

However, the output is separated for each item:

```
    Directory: C:\MyPath\dir1

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          2022-01-22  5:34 PM              0 1.txt


    Directory: C:\MyPath\dir1

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          2022-01-22  5:34 PM              0 2.txt


    Directory: C:\MyPath\dir1

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          2022-01-22  5:34 PM              0 3.txt
```

How can I use the function to get the same result as the first command?

Comment: You would have to place it in either the begin, or end clause (*preferably begin*). This is because, the *process* block processes each item in the pipeline one at time. While the *begin* block would run just once, same for the *end* block which is usually used for cleanup. This kind of defeats the whole purpose in my opinion though, 'cause you just do what you're already doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Abraham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) pointed out in his comment, you could capture all objects coming from the pipeline first and then output the objects *as a stream* so that it is displayed properly in the console.

It's important to note that both examples displayed below, are not truly ***"streaming functions"***, as [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70826467/15339544) has pointed out in his helpful answer, both functions are first **collecting all input coming from pipeline** and then outputting the objects as a *stream of strings* at once, rather than *object by object*.

```bash
function f {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [object] $Content
    )

    begin { $output = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new() }
    process { $output.Add($Content) }
    end { $output | Out-String -Stream }
}
```

As an alternative to the [advanced function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.2) posted above, the example below would also work because of how the [automatic variable `$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input) works in the [`end` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#end) by *enumerating the collection of all input to the function*:

```bash
function f { $input | Out-String -Stream }
```

Comment: The `$input`-based solution is simple and effective, but it's worth noting that it buffers all input up front. The first solution won't work as intended, because the `$Content` object is `.ToString()`-stringified rather than being passed to PowerShell's formatting system for stringification, which is what `Out-String` does. To wrap `Out-String -Stream` in true streaming fashion, you need a _proxy function_.

Comment: @mklement0 the first function was meant to not break the output rather than to replicate `Out-String -Stream`. I thought about a proxy command, but is copy pasting it a valid answer?

Comment: Well, the question is specifically about wrapping `Out-String -Stream` and getting the same output. You mean pasting the source code of `oss`? I think that's OK, as it allows studying the techniques used (as you've since noted, it is what I did in my answer) - and can serve as the basis for wrapping other commands.

Comment: @mklement0 following your first comment, as I see it, both functions in my answer are doing something similar (collecting all input from pipeline and passing the collection to `Out-String -Stream`)

Comment: Good point - for some reason I missed that you're calling `Out-String -Stream` in the `end` block.  So +1 for that solution, which, as you note, is an advanced-function counterpart to the simple `$input`-based function, but the limitation that they share (which may not matter in practice) is their non-streaming nature.

Comment: @mklement0 oh yes, I totally agree with both function's limitation. I think OP's question is very valid if it's meant to understand how the pipeline works and why does `oss` behaves as it does, but I think iRon was on point with the educational statement _"I suspect that you either have a rare requirement or do not fully understand the PowerShell Pipeline..."_

Comment: That's also a good point, but ultimately we can't know what the real use case is. The fact that the `oss` function is _included with PowerShell_ is a pointer that it has its uses and the prime candidate is to make up for `Select-String`'s useless behavior with _non-string_ input objects - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52615947/45375)

Answer (score 5):

I think this question requires a counter question:

#### *Why* do you want to get objects from a pipeline as strings?

I suspect that you either have a *rare* requirement or do not fully understand the [PowerShell Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines)

In general, I would avoid using [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility) in the middle of the pipeline¹ as although [it can be called from the middle of a pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines#implement-for-the-middle-of-a-pipeline), it already formats the output similar to [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) which is usually done at the end of the stream. The point is also that it is hard to determine the width of the columns upfront without knowing what comes next.

1. With the exception mentioned by [**@mklement0**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0):
   There's one good reason to use `Out-String -Stream`: to make up for `Select-String`'s useless behavior with non-string input objects. In fact, PowerShell ships with proxy function oss, which wraps `Out-String -Stream` - see also: [GitHub issue #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726#issuecomment-567628146) and his [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70826467/1701026).

The `Out-String -Stream` parameter also doesn't help for this as all it does is breaking the multiline string into separate strings:

> By default, `Out-String` outputs a single string formatted as you would see it in the console including any blank headers or trailing newlines. The Stream parameter enables `Out-String` to output each line one by one. **The only exception to this are multiline strings. In that case, `Out-String` will still output the string as a single, multiline string.**

```
(ls  | Out-String -Stream).count
8

(ls  | Out-String -Stream)[3]
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
```

But if you really have a need to devaluate the [PowerShell Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject) (which are optimized for streaming) to strings (*without choking* the pipeline), you might actually do this:

```
function f {
    [CmdletBinding()] param ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]$Content)
    begin { $First = $True }
    process {
        if ($First) { $Content |Out-String -Stream |Select-Object -SkipLast 1 }
        else { $Content |Out-String -Stream |Select-Object -Skip 5 |Select-Object -SkipLast 1 }
        $First = $False
    }
}
```

It shows what you are are trying to do, but as said, I would really recommend against this if you do not have a very good reason. The usual way to do this and respecting the pipeline is placing the `Out-String` outside your cmdlet at the end of the stream:

```
ls |f |Out-String -Stream
```

Answer (score 5):

As you've experienced, calling `Out-String -Stream` *for each input object* doesn't work as intended, because - aside from being inefficient - formatting each object in isolation invariably repeats the header in the (table-)formatted output.

The solutions in [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70818346/45375) are effective, but have the **disadvantage of collecting all pipeline input *first***, before processing it, as the following example demonstrates:

```
function f { $input | Out-String -Stream }

# !! Output doesn't appear until after the sleep period.
& { Get-Item $PROFILE; Start-Sleep 2; Get-Item $PROFILE } | f
```

Note: *Output timing* is one aspect, another is *memory use*; neither aspect may or may not matter in a given use case.

---

**To wrap a cmdlet call in *streaming* fashion, where objects are processed *as they become available*, you need a so-called *proxy (wrapper) function*** that utilizes a *steppable pipeline*.

In fact, PowerShell ships with an `oss` function that is a proxy function precisely around `Out-String -Stream`, as a convenient shortcut to the latter:

```
# Streaming behavior via the built-in proxy function oss:
# First output object appears *right away*.
& { Get-Item $PROFILE; Start-Sleep 2; Get-Item $PROFILE } | oss
```

Definition of proxy function `oss` (wraps `Out-String -Stream`); function body obtained with `$function:oss`:

```
function oss {

  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [ValidateRange(2, 2147483647)]
    [int]
    ${Width},
  
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [psobject]
    ${InputObject})
  
  begin {
    $PSBoundParameters['Stream'] = $true
    $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Out-String', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
    $scriptCmd = { & $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
  
    $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
    $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
  }
  
  process {
    $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
  }
  
  end {
    $steppablePipeline.End()
  }
  <#
  .ForwardHelpTargetName Out-String
  .ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet
  #>
  
}
```

Note:

- Most of the body is *generated* code - only the name of the wrapped cmdlet - `Out-String` - and its argument - `-Stream` - are specific to the function.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375) for more information.