# In a powershell pipeline, how to wait for a cmdlet to complete before proceding to the next one?

Tags: powershell

Consider the following function:

```
function myFunction {
  100
  sleep 1
  200
  sleep 1
  300
  sleep 1
}
```

As you can see it will emit those values, one by one down the pipeline.

**But** I want to wait for all the values to be emitted before going on. Like

```
myFunction | waitForThePreviousCommandToComplete | Format-Table
```

I want the Format-Table above to receive the entire array, instead of one-by-one items.

Is it even possible in Powershell?

Comment: `waitForThePreviousCommandToComplete` would need to capture all items coming from the pipeline before outputting (in it's `end` block) in that case. here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/70818346/15339544

Comment: Surrounding any part of the pipeline with parentheses would have that execute first fully before sending output down the pipeline e.g. `(myFunction) | Format-Table`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use
**`(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) in order to **collect a command's output in full first**, before sending it to the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) (the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines)).

```bash
# Due to (...), doesn't send myfunction's output to Format-Table until it has run 
# to completion and all its output has been collected.
(myFunction) | Format-Table

# Also works for entire pipelines.
(100, 200, 300 | ForEach-Object { $_; Start-Sleep 1 }) | Format-Table
```

Note:

- If you need to up-front collect the output of *multiple* commands (pipelines) and / or  language statements, use `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) instead, e.g. 
  `$(Get-Date -Year 2020; Get-Date -Year 2030) | Format-Table`; the next point applies to it as well.
- Whatever output was collected by `(...)` is *enumerated*, i.e., if the collected output is an enumerable, its elements are emitted *one by one* to the success output stream - albeit without any delay at that point.

  - Note that the collected output is *invariably* an enumerable (an array of type `[object[]]`) if *two or more* output objects were collected, but it also can be one in the usual event that a single object that *itself* is an enumerable was collected.
  - E.g., `(Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2, 3)  | Measure-Object` reports a count of `3`, even though `Write-Output -NoEnumerate` output the given array as a *single* object (without `(...)`, `Measure-Object` would report `1`).
- **Typically, commands (cmdlets, functions, scripts) *stream* their output objects, i.e. emit them *one by one* to the pipeline, as soon as they are produced, *while the command is still running***, as your function does, and also act on their pipeline *input* one by one. However, some cmdlets *invariably, themselves* collect all input objects first, before they start emitting their output object(s), *of conceptual necessity*: notable examples are [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object), [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object), and [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object), all of which must act on the *entirety* of their input before they can start emitting results. Ditto for `Format-Table` when it is passed the `-AutoSize` switch, discussed next.
- In the case of **[`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)**, specifically, you can use the **`-AutoSize`** switch in order force *it* to collect all input first, in order to determine suitable display column widths based on *all* data (by default, `Format-Table` waits for 300 msecs. in order to determine column widths, based on whatever subset of the input data it has received by then).

  - However, this does *not* apply to so-called *out-of-band*-formatted objects, notably *strings* and *primitive* .NET types, which are still emitted (by their culture-invariant `.ToString()` representation) as they're being received.
  - Only *complex* objects (those with properties) are collected first, notably [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) and `[pscustomobject]` instances; e.g.:

    ```bash
    # Because this ForEach-Object call outputs complex objects (hashtables),
    # Format-Table, due to -AutoSize, collects them all first,
    # before producing its formatted output.
    100, 200, 300 | ForEach-Object { @{ num = $_ }; Start-Sleep 1 } |
      Format-Table -AutoSize
    ```

If you want to **create a *custom function*** that collects all of its pipeline input up front, you have two options:

- Create a *simple* function that uses the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) in its function body, which *implicitly* runs only *after* all input has been received; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # This simple function simply relays its input, but 
  # implicitly only after all of it has been collected.
  function waitForThePreviousCommandToComplete { $input }

  # Output doesn't appear until after the ForEach-Object
  # call has emitted all its output.
  100, 200, 300 | ForEach-Object { $_; Start-Sleep 1 } | waitForThePreviousCommandToComplete
  ```
- In the context of an [*advanced* function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced), you'll have to *manually* collect all input, iteratively in the `process` block, via a list-type instance allocated in the `begin` block, which you can then process in the `end` block.

  - While using a *simple* function with `$input` is obviously simpler, you may still want an *advanced* one for all the additional benefits it offers (preventing unbound arguments, parameter validation, multiple pipeline-binding parameters, ...).
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70818346/15339544) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Sort waits until it has everything.

```
myFunction | sort-object
```

Or:

```
(myFunction) 
$(myfunction1; myFunction2)
myFunction | format-table -autosize
myFunction | more
```

See also:  [How to tell PowerShell to wait for each command to end before starting the next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next)

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason, just putting the function inside brackets solved my problem:

```
(myFunction) | Format-Table
```

Comment: It's explained above.

Comment: My updated answer now explains in more detail why `(...)` is needed, but in short: PowerShell commands  typically _stream_ their output, i.e. emit their output objects _as they're being produced_, _before_ the command has completed. `(...)` forces collection of all output objects _first_, before sending them on.